# Cookies doesn't work with Cross-site config. I'm using React (Next.js) and Node.js (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I'm working in an app with React with Next.js in the frontend and Node.js with Express in the backend.
My login works with cookies, in localhost all works better, but when I make the deploy, I have two apps. My frontend app is deployed in now.sh and My backend app is deployed in Heroku. When I try to make a login request in production, all works fine, the cookies are in the response and the header 'Set-Cookie' exists. But my browser (Chrome) doesn't store the cookie in Application >> Cookies and obviously my frontend app doesn't know about the cookie and it's undefined

**Here is my code:**

**Server.js**

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL, // contains the frontend url
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  })
);
```

**Auth routes when I make the response to the frontend**

```
return res
      .cookie("token", session.token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "None",
        maxAge: 1209600000,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      })
      .status(200)
      .json({
        success: true,
        token: session.token,
        user,
      });
```

**Making the request in the frontend**

```
const { data } = await Axios.post(login, // backend url to make the request
      { email, password },
      { withCredentials: true });
```

**Response in the browser**

[image]

**Cookie info in the cookie tab**

[image]

Comment: One way to debug your issue if you are using express, create a middleware that will print in the server the headers of the request to see, what information you are working with, I guess should be `console.log(request.headers)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm trying

Comment: @NicolásLeal were you able to resolve this? I need to take my application to production and facing exactly the same issue

Comment: @KaranKumar no ): I can't solve this issue. I think Google changed their policies and now we can't make this type of requets.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? Same thing for spring-boot application and next.js for the client application. Everything is good on local, production not working.

Comment: @NicolásLeal did you manage fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I see that the token cookie you are setting is a `http-only` cookie, so it will not be available to your application.

As quoted in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Restrict_access_to_cookies)

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it is sent only to the server. For example, cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript, and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: Now if I make a request to the backend with an authorization validation it works but in the frontend the cookie doesn't exists 

Comment: Sorry, u mean, u will not be able to access the cookie in the Javascript right?

Comment: For example, If I want to make a get request to retrieve users from my app, that endpoint in the backend needs cookie authorization (it's middleware). When I make the request in the frontend, everything works, but the cookie is not stored in the browser in application> Store> Cookies and when you login it should be stored there

Answer (score 1):

I've been through this 'cookie' issue for the past few days banging my head against the wall. Try to add this line to your server.js before session settings:

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```